# what is the purpose of __weak reference used on Keil MDK ARM?

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, cortex-m4

Got a little messy with a function defined in two files and one with a __weak symbol.
I called the below function to load the settings of UART1 in STM32L476RG from my main file

```
 if(HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle) != HAL_OK) and this function is defined at 
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

I found that this function calls another funciton named  `HAL_UART_MspInit(huart);`
This is defined at two places ,

```
 1. in stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c as void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef
    *huart)
 2. in stm32l4xx_hal_uart.c as __weak void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
```

My problem is that the whenever I load the UART setting the __weak function is called. I did it by referring an example, UART_WakeUpFromStop given in the [[STM32F476RG Product page]](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubel4.html). where in the example the function in  nstm32l4xx_hal_msp.c , void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) is called. What is going wrong in my code? what is the influence of __weak symbol?

[STM32L476RG Reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf)

Comment: __weak functions are usually placeholders or defaults and you can override them with another function by simply declaring it with the same name. Are you *sure* your 'real' non-weak function is really being compiled & linked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo that The definition and implementation can be overridden with a non weak type, aka user defined one.

Check the manual to bee suit..

Comment: but why is it going to a weak type in my code?